# get current CallBack count?

Tags: java, gwt, callback

Is its possible to get how many Callbacks like below are current running?

```
(new AsyncCallback<List<data>>()
    {

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable caught)
        {
        }

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(List<PersonalData> result)
        {

        }
    });
```

Comment: Why would you want to count them? You could use a field in the server-side servlet that is incremented/decremented for every start and end of an async method call

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use my own ExtendedAsyncCallback. It allows me to block the UI when some callbacks are still active. Note that it also allows me to avoid cutting and pasting `onFailure` in every callback.

```
public class ExtendedAsyncCallback<T> implements AsyncCallback<T> {

    private static int activeCallbacks;

    public ExtendedAsyncCallback() {
        // here I block the UI and show a nice spinner
        activeCallbacks++;
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
        activeCallbacks--;
        // show an error message depending on exception
    }

    @Override
    public void onSuccess(T result) {
        activeCallbacks--;
        if (activeCallbacks == 0) {
            // here I hide my spinner
        }
        execute(result);
    }

    public void execute(T result) {
        // I use this method in presenters instead of 'onSuccess'
    }
```

Then you call becomes:

```
(new ExtendedAsyncCallback<Object>() {

    @Override
    public void execute(Object result) {

    }
});
```

Comment: +1, I used same logic in my last project and it works perfectly. I think `execute()` method should be `abstract`, Isn't it?

Comment: From Java docs: If a class includes abstract methods, then the class itself must be declared abstract. Abstract classes cannot be instantiated.

Comment: I am talking about anonymous class as we did for `AsyncCallback`. It means whenever this class is used at that point, it's needed to provide the implementation of `execute()` method as well.

Comment: The `onSuccess` method should probably be final to avoid accidentally overriding that (making the `ExtendedAsyncCallback` and `execute` abstract would also help). Also, don't forget about making `onFailure` decrement `activeCallbacks`, since otherwise it can never reach zero id if a single thing fails at any time in the app's running time.

Comment: @Colin - Good points. Actually, I have a more complex logic where some RPC calls block the UI, while other calls do not. So I override onSuccess() in some calls and execute() in the other calls. I just gave a general idea of how to approach this problem - it needs to be adapted depending on a use case.